How to implement i18next translation in a React project
When you press the buttons, the language should change:
<a href="/" className={`bn5 ${i18next.language === LOCALES.UK ? 'disabled-link' : ''}`} onClick={handleUkrlanguage}>Ukrainian</a>
<a href="/" className={`bn5 ${i18next.language === LOCALES.EN ? 'disabled-link' : ''}`} onClick={handleEngLanguage}>English</a>

Changing the state of buttons via Redux is correct. This is confirmed by the output in console.log().
I think the problem is that i18next does not receive translations even after changing the language.
Below I will give you the code of the component and you will see the console.log() and their results.
import './header.css';
import gsap from 'gsap';
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { ukrLanguage, engLanguage } from '../../redux/actions';
import i18next from 'i18next';
import { LOCALES } from '../i18n/constants';
import { Trans, useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';
import '../i18n/index';

const Header = () => {
  const heroRef = useRef(null);
  const { t } = useTranslation();
  const selectedLanguage = useSelector(state => state.language.selectedLanguage);

  useEffect(() => {
    const tl = gsap.timeline();
    tl.fromTo(heroRef.current, { x: -100, opacity: 0 }, { x: 0, opacity: 1, duration: 2 }, 1);
  }, []);


  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('Changing language to:', selectedLanguage);
    i18next.changeLanguage(selectedLanguage).then(() => {
      console.log('Language changed to:', i18next.language);
      console.log('Current translations:', i18next.getDataByLanguage(i18next.language));
      console.log('t("Welcome to React"):', t('Welcome to React'));
    }).catch(err => {
      console.error('Error changing language:', err);
    });
  }, [selectedLanguage]);

  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const handleUkrlanguage = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log('Switching to Ukrainian');
    dispatch(ukrLanguage());
  }

  const handleEngLanguage = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log('Switching to English');
    dispatch(engLanguage());
  }
  console.log('Rendering Header with language:', i18next.language);
  console.log('Current translations in Header:', i18next.getDataByLanguage(i18next.language));
  console.log('t("Welcome to React") in render:', t('Welcome to React'));

  return (
    <header className='header'>
      <div className="container header__container">
        <div className="header__wrapper">
          <a href="#" className='header__hero' ref={heroRef}>
            <span className='header__surname'>My </span>
            <span className='first__name'>CV</span>
          </a>
          <div className="lng__btns-wrapper">
            <h3>{selectedLanguage}</h3>
            <a href="/" className={`bn5 ${i18next.language === LOCALES.UK ? 'disabled-link' : ''}`} onClick={handleUkrlanguage}>Ukrainian</a>
            <a href="/" className={`bn5 ${i18next.language === LOCALES.EN ? 'disabled-link' : ''}`} onClick={handleEngLanguage}>English</a>
            </div>
          <h3>{t('Welcome to React')}</h3>
          <h3><Trans>Welcome to React</Trans></h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>
  );
}

export default Header;


I understand that there is a lot of code and I would be grateful if you could download the repository to your local computer and help me. I have been trying to solve the problem of why it does not translate text for a week: https://github.com/Bilostenko/cv_profile.git
Here what I receive:
Initializing i18next with resources: {en: {…}, uk: {…}}
index.js:31 i18next initialized with language: EN
index.js:32 Available resources: {en: {…}, uk: {…}}
Rendering App with language: EN
Header.jsx:46 Rendering Header with language: EN
**Header.jsx:47 Current translations in Header: undefined**
Header.jsx:48 t("Welcome to React") in render: Ласкаво просимо до React
Changing language to: UK
index.js:37 Language changed to: UK
**index.js:38 Current translations: undefined**
Header.jsx:26 Language changed to: UK
**Header.jsx:27 Current translations: undefined**
Header.jsx:28 t("Welcome to React"): Ласкаво просимо до React
Header.jsx:46 Rendering Header with language: UK
**Header.jsx:47 Current translations in Header: undefined**
Header.jsx:48 t("Welcome to React") in render: Ласкаво просимо до React


The problem is most likely because you are calling changeLanguage on  i18next imported directly from the underlying i18next library.
Anything you call directly on this isn't going through react-i18next. You need to pull the i18n object from the react-i18next context and call that changeLanguage instead. That will  invoke additional bindings react-i18next adds and cause the provider to refresh all the t calls via its context.
const { t, i18n } = useTranslation();

// Now you can call changeLanguage using this i18n where needed.
// Avoid using imported i18n in your component render.

This change to use i18n from the useTranslation() hook will be needed throughout. There should be nothing referencing the imported one from inside the components, apart from the initial setup to the provider.
Separately, unless I didn't look hard enough, I noticed in the repo provided your language catalogue files are missing, but I assume you have them locally. You need to do all the translations themselves, register all of your translation bundles etc.
